How to model a more generalized hyperbolic constraint as an SOCP constraint?
It is well known that the hyperbolic constraint $xy \ge t^2$ can be modeled as an SOCP constraint by the following transformation $\frac{1}{4}(x+y)^2 \ge t^2 + \frac{1}{4}(x-y)^2  \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{2}(x+y) \ge \sqrt{t^2+ (\frac{1}{2}(x-y))^2} $.
Now suppose that this constraint is extended to $xy + ab \ge t^2$ or even more general $x_1x_2 + x_3x_4 + ...  + x_{n-1}x_n \ge t^2$.
Is it possible to present these two cases as an SOCP constraints ?
